# Segmentation fault with std::function and lambda parameters

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda

Can you please explain why this code crashes? I would expect output of "a", but I get segmentation fault.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

struct MyStruct {
  vector<string> a;
  vector<string> b;
};

void out_data(const MyStruct& my_struct, const std::function<const vector<string>&(const MyStruct&)> getter) {
  cout << getter(my_struct)[0] << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  MyStruct my_struct;
  my_struct.a.push_back("a");
  my_struct.b.push_back("b");
  out_data(my_struct, [](const MyStruct& in) {return in.a;});
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably because the lambda returns the vector *by value* and not by reference.

Comment: If you see yourself ever returning a reference, ask yourself "where does that object I'm referring to lives"? If you can't answer, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Please enable warnings.  Your compiler was probably screaming at you that this was a bad idea.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The

```
[](const MyStruct& in) {return in.a;}
```

*lambda expression* is equivalent to

```
[](const MyStruct& in) -> auto {return in.a;}
```

which returns a copy of `in.a`. Your `std::function` signature then returns a dangling reference to a local object.

---

Change the *lambda expression* to

```
[](const MyStruct& in) -> const auto& {return in.a;}
```

to return a `const&` instead, fixing the segfault.

---

Also, don't use `std::function` to pass lambdas unless you have a good reason to do so. I suggest reading my article on the subject: [**"passing functions to functions"**](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html).

Answer (score 7):

I blame `std::function` (and you). I blame you, of course, for asking `std::function` to return a dangling reference, as explained by Vittorio Romeo. But I also blame `std::function`'s constructor template for not checking for this case, which should be in most or all cases detectable at compile time, and consequently generating a diagnostic. (I use the word "blame" only to point out possible areas of improvement. In that sense, I also blame myself for not having thought of adding this exact check in the implementation of my own `unique_function` class template.)

Let's take a closer look at the constructor's signature. I chose the definition site for this purpose.

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
template<typename F>
std::function<R(Args...)>::function(F f);
```

It should be possible to ban dangling references here. A dangling reference will be returned from the `operator()` if and only if `R` is a reference to a temporary returned by `F`. Let's define (in the scope of the constructor body):

```
using RF = decltype(f(std::forward<Args>()...));
```

Now we can be almost certain that a dangling reference will be returned from the `function`'s `operator()` if:

```
std::is_reference<R>::value && ! std::is_reference<RF>::value
```

There is a catch, though, in that `RF` could be a class type with a user-defined conversion operator to `R`. Although this conversion may still be unsafe, we don't have sufficient information at this point to decide, and should err on the side of generality. Obviously, we could detect whether the target of `R` is a public base class of `RF` (this is assuming the above condition is true):

```
std::is_convertible<RF *, typename std::remove_reference<R>::type *>::value
```

I only allow public inheritance here because `std::function` can only access public non-ambiguous base classes. Unless someone made `std::function` a `friend` of `RF` for some strange reason. (Since the conversion can be done inside the wrapped function object, there is probably no need to do this.)

Putting it all together and inverting the logic, we could prefix the `function` constructor's body with:

```
using RF = decltype(f(std::forward<Args>()...));
static_assert( ! std::is_reference<R>::value  ||
                 std::is_reference<RF>::value ||
               ! std::is_convertible<RF *, typename std::remove_reference<R>::type *>::value,
               "Using this function object would result in a dangling reference in the function call" );
```

Comment: Even though this is not an answer, I upvoted as it's valuable information. Have you considered researching this further and writing a proposal/DR?

Comment: I came to this post to blame somebody but there is nobody left to blame to :)